# Necron unit from "Hellforged" described as "a titanic metal-shod beetle"

Tags: character-identification, warhammer-40k

I'm reading [*Hellforged*](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Hellforged_(Novel)) by Ben Counter and there is a description of a Necron that I don't recognize, can anyone tell me what it is?

> It was shaped like a titanic metal-shod beetle, pulling itself along
>   on its belly with thousands of legs that writhed along its sides.
>
> Its head was a huge maw, ringed with steel teeth, with power glowing
>   in its throat. Scarabs crawled all over its surface, and behind its
>   long segmented tail it left a deep furrow in the ground as it drove
>   forwards, flanked by the march of the Undying.
>
> The machine's enormous bulk pushed down one of the gatehouses, and
>   tonnes of rubble were sucked into its maw. The useless matter was
>   siphoned off and spewed from vents along its sides as clouds of
>   choking dust.

Comment: Googling `"It was shaped like a titanic metal-shod beetle"` only turns up 3 results for me, a pdf download for _Hellforged_, [this forum](http://www.warseer.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-213110.html) where a user calls it a Harvester and [this one](http://bbs.stardestroyer.net/viewtopic.php?t=152876&start=25) where they state _"Anothr Necron, non monolith superheavy. Don't think we've seen this in the game."_ - It appears that there is next to no information on it.

Comment: From [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/40kLore/comments/6x6ayq/are_there_any_necron_titans/): _"There's also mention of a giant sort of harvester serpent in the novel Hellforged that operates in a somewhat similar manner as scarabs, breaking down buildings, vehicles, people, anything that it happened to "consume" into raw materials."_

Comment: I can't find anything else other than similar comments by other people. There doesn't appear to be anything "official" on this from my search so I won't leave an answer.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot ah I see, thanks for all the research! That's a pity it might not actually exist, I was looking forward to seeing it.

Comment: I'm not a W40K fan so there might be something that others are aware of, that's just all I could find from a few quick searches.

Comment: @Daft - I don't think there is officially anything that matches the description you have posted. I think this is another example of authors expanding the universe from what we already know and putting their own twists on things... Reading that I envision a combination of that beetle from Starship Troopers pulling its belly along the ground and a centipede with a bunch of little legs all working in unison... I like it!

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, hard to match it - lots of Necron units look like beetle-like...

It could be a Crypt Stalker:

[image]

But apparently it has been encountered only once, so indeed it is a rare beast. Crypt Stalker is an upsized version of a regular Tomb/Canoptek Spyder

[image]

[image]

But the latter one, while quite common is not particularly big - about the size of a regular truck (note, the guy on the right is about 2.5-3 meters tall)

[image]

Another possibility is the World Harvester (aka as Abattoir), which has a lot of tentacle-like appendages used to pull everything that moves and kill it in the name of C'tan:

[image]

It is indeed described as a gigantic, floating building, but not as much as "beetle".